# Can't parse WCF Post request json body correctly

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have a post request being sent to my RESTful API in the following format

**Headers**

```
Host: localhost:9475
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 59
```

**Body**

`{"query":"SOME STRING","variables":{"Foo":{"Data":"ABCD"}}}`

I'm trying to receive the data in the body of the request, so this is what i've tried:

`public void foo(string query, object variables)`

The **query** parameter is being parsed correctly but the **variables** parameter always gets `{object}` as its value.

`public void foo(string query, Dictionary<string, object> variables)`

The **query** parameter is being parsed correctly but the **variables** parameter is a dictionary with no keys/values.

`public void foo(string query, VariablesObj variables)`

where **VariablesObj**

```
public class VariablesObj
{
   public object input_0 {get; set;}
}
```

The **query** parameter is being parsed correctly and the **variables** parameter has one property **input_0** with the value of `{object}`.

Am i doing something wrong? or am i missing something that i need to implement for this to work.

**Edit 1:**

I tried @rene's answer and it worked for this scenario, but my problem now is that the object inside `Foo` is not always the same as i'm using GraphQl with Relay on the client side and it changes the variables to whatever object it needs to send but it's usually just one object inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a proper mapping make sure you have a class with a public property Foo which is of a type that has a public property Data of type string.

If this is your public interface

```
public void foo(string query, MyVars variables)
```

you'll need the following classes:

```
public class MyVars 
{
     public DataVars Foo { get; set; }
}

public class DataVars 
{
    public string Data { get; set;}
}
```

You can quickly test this with the [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var json = @"{""query"":""SOME STRING"",""variables"":{""Foo"":{""Data"":""ABCD""}}}";

var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(wrapper));
var sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
var mv = (wrapper) ser.ReadObject(sr);
mv.Dump();
```

I add one extra wrapper type as a stand-in for the the method signature:

```
   public class wrapper
   {
       public string query {get; set;}
       public MyVars variables { get;set;}
   }
```

When run in LinqPad this will be the result:

[image: linqpad result]

Which proves that our class hierarchy is correct to fully deserialize the given Json.

When your variables can be of all kind of data shapes you have to define as much class as you need to cover those and supply them on the specialized constructor that takes a list of knowntypes: [`DataContractJsonSerializer Constructor (Type, IEnumerable<Type>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908209(v=vs.110).aspx). The process to make design those classes doesn't change, you'll only have a bunch of them. Add the [`KnownType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to your datacontract classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i tried what you have suggested and it worked, but i'm facing another problem which is the object inside the Foo is not the same with every request. I'm using GraphQl and it sends the same body with different data in the variables depending on the request sent from the client side.

Comment: @SamNasser you need either have a class for every scenario or a class the covers all possible attributes. I added a link to the constructor that will do that trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will give it a try. Also i will mark the question as an answer as it answered my first question.